# Laravel depth first tree traversal

Tags: mysql, laravel

so the php framework I'm using is Laravel. I have a comment table, and comment are allowed to have child comments. I ordered the comments by updated time:

```
$post->comments()->orderBy('updated_at')->paginate(10);
```

Now I want to group the comments so that all the child comments with the same parent comment are put together, i.e., parent comment, then all of its child comments one by one, then next parent comment, then all of its child comments one by one, etc. Like the following:

- comment1
- subcommentA of comment1
- subcommentB of comment1
- comment2
- subcommentC of comment2
- subcommentD of comment2
- subcommentE of subcommentD
- ...

Now this order cannot be done by a simple 'orderBy', my question is: can I accomplish this with Laravel query builder/eloquent, or do I have to order manually? By the way, I have set up the Comment model so that its parent/children can be fetched by:

```
$comment->parentComment;
$comment->childComments;
```

Comment: Being it a tree structure makes it a bit hard, because you can end up with multiple (in theory infinite) queries, but the easiest way would be simply loading comments with children recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that if I have to order all the comments of a post everytime I fetch data from database, it may eventually lead to big performance issue. So my workaround is as follows:
First off, this is my comment table:

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| content           | varchar(2000)    | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| author_id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| post_id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| parent_comment_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| level             | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
| sort_order        | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at        | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

Notice that there's a field called sort_order, every time there is a new comment added to the post, one of the following two things happen to decide the value of the newComment's sort_order:

1. If the comment has no parent, then

   $newComment->sort_order = Comment::max('sort_order') + 1;
2. If the comment has parent, then

   ```
   $parent = $newComment->parentComment;
   $newComment->sort_order = $parent->sort_order + 1;
   // for all the comments that have sort_order larger than the parent of the newly added comment, add their sort_order by 1
   $comments_to_be_updated = Comment::where('sort_order', '>', $parent->sort_order)->get();
   foreach ($comments_to_be_updated as $comment_to_be_updated) {
       $comment_to_be_updated->sort_order += 1;
       $comment_to_be_updated->save();
   }
   ```

   This way, every time a new comment is added, its position/order is finalized and recorded by sort_order, when I want to fetch comments of a post with the desired order, all I need is:

   $post->comments->orderBy('sort_order')->paginate(10);

Now, I'm not saying this is the solution, but it's tested and works in my scenario, if you have any suggestions/criticisms in regards to database performance or anything, please do, I'm open for advice and discussions.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this using a model relationship (self), for example, assume that this is your `comments` table:

```
id (PK) | content | post_id | user_id | comment_parent
------------------------------------------------------
1       | Hello   | 1       | 1       | 0 <-- This is a parent because of 0
2       | Hi      | 1       | 2       | 1 <-- child of 1
3       | Howdy   | 1       | 3       | 1 <-- child of 1
```

Read that table as: there are total three comments, the first comment is made by the `User` with `user_id-1` and it has two child comments made by other two users whose `id`'s are `user_id-2` and `user_id-3`.

Here, the `comment_parent` column keeps a relationship between `parent` and `child` comments. The `comment_parent` with value of `0` is a parent comment and other than `0`, for example, here two comments have `comment_parent` of `1` which means these two comments are child of the comment whose `id/PK` is `1`.

So, now, in your `Comment` model declare these methods:

```
// Get only children of a comment
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'comment_parent');
}

// Get the user of comment
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}

// Get the post of comment
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Post', 'post_id');
}
```

Then in your `Post` model declare this method:

```
// Only parent comments
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'post_id')->where('comment_parent', 0);
}

// All Comments
public function allComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'post_id');
}
```

Now, if you do something like this:

```
$post = Post::with('comments.children')->find(1);
```

Then you may try something like this in your view (Probably in your `post.single.blade.php`):

```
{{ $post->title }}
{{ $post->body }}

<!-- Comment Template For Posting New Comments-->

@if($post->comments->count())

    @foreach($post->comments as $comment)

        {{ $comment->user->username }}
        {{ $comment->body }}

        @if($comment->children->count())

            @foreach($comment->children as $childComment)

                {{ $childComment->user->username }}
                {{ $childComment->body }}

            @endforeach

        @endif

    @endforeach

@endif
```

This is an idea and in this case, your comments will have `0` as `comment_parent` by default and when a comment is a reply to another comment then set it's `comment_parent` to it's parent's `id`. Also, you may check [this article](http://heera.it/laravel-model-relationship#.VCyYI_mSySp) for a different approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer. This one works I believe, although I thinks there's a big prerequisite here: the comment tree has a maximum depth of 2. In my first thought, I think a comment system allows for infinite depth, meaning that no matter how far comment A is far away from its first ancestor (say comment A is the grandson of grandson of grandson ... of the comment B), comment A is still open for another child comment... so in my case, I think recursion is a have-to.

Comment: Then you may follow the link I gave you :-)